# How can I rename "Appendices" in the Table of Contents and in the text?

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, naming

I would like to change the name of the "Appendices" to "Appendix" in the Table of Contents. So far, I was only able to change the name of the Appendices in the text, by using the following commands in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendix}
```

Also, I was able to add "Appendix" to the Table of Contents by using the command:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
```

However, using this I have both the default "Appendices" and the added "Appendix" in the Table of Contents. Does anyone know how to remove or rename "Appendices" in the Table of Contents?

Comment: Are you using the `appendix` package?

Comment: If yes, try `\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendix}` but if you provide a MWE it would be better...

Comment: Yes, I am using the appendix package. Thx!! This solved it!

Answer (score 20):

So we are talking about the [`appendix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package.

The command `\appendixpagename` is used to give a name to the heading of the page generated when you use the `\appendixpage` command.

If you want to change the name that appears in the TOC when you (supposedly) use the command `\addappheadtotoc` to add this page in the TOC itself, you have to use:

```
\renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendix}
```

Note that both `\appendixpagename` and `\appendixtocname` are by default set to "Appendices".

Comment: If someone else struggles like me: the commands named in this answer have to be placed before the beginning of the appendencies section.

Comment: Strangely, `\renewcommand\appendixtocname` works for me even if put in the document header, but `\renewcommand\appendixname` has no effect unless placed directly before `\begin{appendices}` as suggested by the previous comment.